# c - passing a pointer to a function with a parameter of void* variable

Tags: c

I want to pass a pointer to a variable. Sometimes it would be an integer and sometimes maybe a character. In the example below i pass the pointer `p` to `CreateObject` but when i try to retrieve the value of the variable the pointer points to i get an awkward result:

```
int i =0;
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
*p = i;

ObjectP object = CreateObject(p);
```

Say i want to cast it back to an int and display it:

```
void CreateObject(void *key)
{
   printf("%d\n", (int)key);
}
```

I get: 160637064 instead of 0. What am i getting instead of the integer i assigned previously and how do i retrieve it instead of the current value?

Comment: And, out of curiosity, how do you plan to distinguish the size of the element passed? Another parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
(int) key
```

is not dereferencing the pointer to access the data it points at, it's re-interpreting the pointer value (the address) itself as the integer.

You need:

```
printf("%d\n", *(int *) key);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're typecasting a pointer to an integer. This means that you simply get the address. After all, a pointer is just an address.

You probably want to dereference the pointer instead of casting it. `*(int*)key` would do that.

Answer (score 3):

You're printing the pointer, ie. the address, not the value that it's pointing to.

Use this to print the value:

```
void CreateObject(void *key)
{
   printf("%d\n", *(int*)key);
}
```